# Haskell Monoid Instance Question for a newtype

Tags: haskell, monoids, newtype, deriving, derivingvia

I am trying to define an instance:

```
newtype Join a = Join { getJoin :: a -> Bool }
   deriving Generic

instance Monoid (Join a) where
   f <> g = ???
   mempty = ???
```

The goal is that the function foldMap Join should return True if all functions in the list are true, and false if all are not true.

I understand foldMap, and the instances of Sum and Product for Monoid but am otherwise quite new to writting newtype instances of Monoid. Any help in the right direction would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

You can make an new function that returns `True` if both the first and second function return `True`, by using `(&&)`. Then the `mempty` is a `Join` function that is `True` for all input:

```
instance Monoid (Join a) where
    Join f <> Join g = Join (\x -> f x && g x)
    mempty = Join (const True)
```

Since the introduction of the `Semigroup`, the `(<>)` function is an instance of the `Semigroup` however:

```
import Control.Applicative(liftA2)

instance Semigroup (Join a) where
    Join f <> Join g = Join (liftA2 (&&) f g)

instance Monoid (Join a) where
    mappend = (<>)
    mconcat js = Join (\x -> all (($ x) . getJoin) js)
    mempty = Join (const True)
```

Comment: That makes sense. And I assume using && determines the output of the Bool. I was trying to pattern match for the cases of Join f <> Join g, but that is the wrong approach. I'll have to study what Semigroup is as I haven't encountered it much. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Thunderbird `Semigroup` only defines an associative operation `<>`, and `Monoid` adds a unit `mempty` to that. So a semigroup is a "monoid without mandating a unity".

Answer (score 1):

Your type `Join a` is isomorphic to `a -> All`, which already has the `Monoid` instance that you want. As such, you can get the instance on your type without having to implement anything yourself, like this:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DerivingVia #-}

import Data.Monoid

newtype Join a = Join { getJoin :: a -> Bool }
   deriving Generic -- not needed for the Monoid instance; I only left it here to show you how to do two different kinds of deriving on the same type, since you derived this already in your question
   deriving (Semigroup, Monoid) via a -> All
```