# foldMap Conjoined

Tags: haskell, fold, foldable

I'm trying create this function in Haskell with a given prototype:

```
The function "foldMap Conjoined" over a list of functions returning Bool values
    should produce a function over the same input type that returns True if all of
    the functions in the list return True for the given input, and False if at
    least one of the functions returns False for the given input. (If the list is
    empty, then all of the zero functions in the list return True.)> 

newtype Conjoined a = Conjoined { getConjoined :: a -> Bool }
       deriving Generic
    
instance Monoid (Conjoined a) where
       f <> g = Conjoined (\x -> True)
```

The line f <> g is the start of my portion of the code. With that line, the function passes the associativity test, but it doesn't produce the correct result

Comment: Well `Conjoined (\x -> True)` does not even take `f` and `g` into account. It will always map to `True`.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62982832/67579

Comment: I realize that, but I can't figure out how to structure the f and g arguments to return true false or mempty

Comment: You unwrap the `a -> Bool` from the `Conjoined` data constructor, and then call the functions and combine the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make an new function that returns True if both the first and second function return True, by using (&&). Then the mempty is a [Join] function that is True for all input:
source: stackoverflow.com/q/62982832/67579

taking the same logic and applying it to this 'conjoined' monoid

```
   "instance Monoid (Conjoined a) where
        Conjoined f <> Conjoined g = Conjoined (\x -> f x && g x)
        mempty = Conjoined (const True)"
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.